# how to get data of Case-Shiller U.S. National Home Price Index?

Tags: python

Can I use pandas datareader to get the data of Case-Shiller U.S. National Home Price Index?

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CSUSHPINSA

For example, I use below code to get SPY500 data regulary. Could I do the same for Case-Shiller U.S. National Home Price Index? What ticker do I use?

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 17)
web.DataReader('GOOGL', 'yahoo', start, end)
```

Thanks

Regards,

Comment: What ideas do you have for how this might be done?  Have you tried anything yet?  Have you looked to see if Pandas has web scraping functionality; that is, can it dig through the HTML of a complicated web page and find graph data embedded therein?  If not, how might you extract the data from the web site to give it to Pandas?

Comment: Thanks Steve, I edit my post to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
web.DataReader('CSUSHPINSA', 'fred', start, end)
```

supported websites are listed here: https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html

including FRED examples:
https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-fred

Comment: Thank you KM_83, that is exactly what I needed. I appreciate it